# Routing without template/controller combo?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-router

I would like to map each route with a function, rather than a controller/template.

I have only 1 page, the only items which change on the page are scope variables. I'd prefer avoiding a controller and template reload, I'd rather just swap the variables.

Is this possible with $routeProvider?

---

Apologies for being unclear, here is an example:

The app is one template and one controller `ThreadCtrl`

```
app.controller("ThreadCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.topic = "all";
  $scope.sorting = "best";
  $scope.articles = get_articles_for_topic(...);
  $scope.$watch "topic", ...
  $scope.$watch "sorting", ...
});
```

template example:

```
<div ng-controller="TopicCtrl">
    {{ topic }} - {{ sorting }}
    <div ng-repeat="article in articles">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

There is always one template and one controller. I'd like to make use of routing without re-rendering the controller and just changing the scope variables.

I understand if for this example I should probably re-render template + controller as default, but I just want to know if I can.

---

An alternative to this question would be **"Can I map a route to a function which has access to a $rootScope?"**

---

Thanks :)

Comment: It's unclear what you asking, could you post a code example

Comment: *"I'd rather just swap the variables."* What variables? Do you have only one template?

Comment: If you have only one page why do you need routing?

Comment: Apologies for being unclear, I hope it's clearer now? I'll re-edit if needed. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make use of the parameters in the route?

You could define route as something like this:

```
when('/Thread/:topic', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/thread.html',
      controller: 'ThreadCtrl'
});
```

and then in controller make use of that parameter:

```
app.controller("ThreadCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.topic = $routeParams.topic;
  $scope.sorting = "best";
  $scope.articles = get_articles_for_topic(...);
  $scope.$watch "topic", ...
  $scope.$watch "sorting", ...
});
```

This is most probably how I would do it, however I'm also curious whether there is better solution to this.